# Extract GCM from google play services using proguard

Tags: android, google-play, google-cloud-messaging, proguard

**You don't have to do it like I wanted to, now it's much simplier, look answer below!**

I want to extract GCM from google play services using proguard (I've run out of 65k method limit, but  **I dont want to** to split dex file). However I'm not able to get rid of this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
```

Here is my proguard config:

```
-injars  sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar
-outjars google-play-services-push.jar

-libraryjars sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar

-verbose
-forceprocessing
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn com.google.**.R
-dontwarn com.google.**.R$*
-dontnote

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.** {
    public protected *;
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.gcm.** {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    java.lang.String NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}
```

Based on https://www.saikoa.com/files/media/ProGuard_DroidconLondon2014.pdf + my tries to keep string resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not required nowadays since you can split the google play servies into separate packages

example:

Google Account Login
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0`

Google Actions, Base Client Library
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0`

Google App Indexing
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0`

Google App Invites
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.3.0`

Google Analytics
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0`

Google Cloud Messaging
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0`

And there's many more - you can find them in the link below (no point in listing them all).

source:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup